# Infinite loop traversing cloud storage file structure [Box api]

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, box-api

I'm trying to get the metadata from the box api and so I need to traverse the entire directory structure. Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)ls {

    // INITIALIZE folderID  (will be nil only for the root folder)

    if (self.folderID == nil)
    {
        self.folderID = BoxAPIFolderIDRoot;
        self.folderName = @"Root";   
    }

    // START TRAVERSING DIRECTORY TREE
    [self traverseItemsWithFolderID:self.folderID name:self.folderName]; 
    }


- (void)traverseItemsWithFolderID:(NSString *)folder name:(NSString *)namefolder

{   
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:folder name:namefolder]; //   <- List Files/dirs in directory namefolder

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   // Create box object "item" to traverse folderItemsArray
    BoxItem * item = (BoxItem *)[self.folderItemsArray objectEnumerator];
    for (item in self.folderItemsArray)
    {
        if([item.type isEqualToString:BoxAPIItemTypeFolder])
            {
                NSLog(@"SubFolder id %@", item.modelID);
                NSLog(@"SubFolder name %@", item.name);
                [self traverseItemsWithFolderID:item.modelID name:item.name];

            }
    }

    });
   });
}

and this last method:

- (void)fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:(NSString *)innerFolder name:(NSString *)innerFolderName
{

    BoxFoldersResourceManager *mgr = [BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager;
    BoxFoldersRequestBuilder *bldr = [[BoxFoldersRequestBuilder alloc] initWithQueryStringParameters:@{ @"fields" : @"name,type,id,etag,size,modified_at,hash" }];

    [mgr folderItemsWithID:innerFolder requestBuilder:bldr success: ^(BoxCollection *collection)
    {
        self.folderItemsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < collection.numberOfEntries; i++)
        {
            [self.folderItemsArray addObject:[collection modelAtIndex:i]];

            NSLog(@"FOLDER NAME %@", innerFolderName);

            BoxItem *item = (BoxItem *)[self.folderItemsArray objectAtIndex:i];

                NSLog(@"Here The list of Files/Directories:");
                NSLog(@"TypE %@", item.type);                    // [file/directory]
                NSLog(@"NAME %@", item.name);                    // filename

                NSLog(@"ID %@", item.ETag);                      // directory level [0 = root]
                NSLog(@"ID %@", item.modelID);                   //  metadata unique identifier [FolderID !]

                NSLog(@"SIZE %@", item.size);                    // in bytes
                NSLog(@"Modified Time %@", item.modifiedAt);     // in UTC format 

                NSLog(@"HASH %lu", (unsigned long)item.hash);   // hash
        }
        self.totalCount = [collection.totalCount integerValue];
        NSLog(@" Number of files/dirs in Level %ld", (long)self.totalCount);
    }
```

The final result is that the code start an infinite loop of requests and don't understand why, as it should stop when there are no more directories. Any help on identifying the issue is much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: hash is not a field returned by the Box API. It is the method hash on NSObject: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash

Comment: Thanks Ryan, you are absolutely right: it does not come from the BOX API (just verified with a breakpoint in the code. Still...the code crashes with the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x8b8fbb0> was mutated while being enumerated.'" My code does not really work because for each directory in box a new task is fired to retrieve the directory metadata. Because the same unique array is used to store the metadatas, all these concurrent threads will end up overwriting the array and causing a crash.

Comment: One first improvement could be to have two asynchronous tasks and a completion handler for the recursive method: the first retrieves the current directory metadata while the second (fired up on completion of the first one) will check for directories as well and then fire up the recursive method for each dir.This may work if each subdir has only one directory, but if it has multiple ones then multiple recursive methods will be fired up at the same time as well. This would eventually cause again the array to be overwritten and the program to crash.

Comment: A solution would be to make all new instances of the recursive method start in a serial way (not in parallel) but this is quite advanced and I was hoping to get this metadata retrieval more easily. 
The best solution would be if an array with all the metadata's info was possible to be collected from the box account via an API method: that's my wishlist for the box developers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the property `self.folderItemsArray` since you have a recursive method, try this:

```
- (NSArray*)fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:(NSString *)innerFolder name:(NSString *)innerFolderName
{
  ...
      // This is a new line.
      NSMutableArray* folderItemsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
      [mgr folderItemsWithID:innerFolder requestBuilder:bldr success: ^(BoxCollection *collection)
  {
     //self.folderItemsArray = [NSMutableArray array]; remove this line.
     for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < collection.numberOfEntries; i++)
     {
        [folderItemsArray addObject:[collection modelAtIndex:i]]; // remove the self here.
     ...
   }
   return folderItemsArray;
}
```

And update this method like this:

```
- (void)traverseItemsWithFolderID:(NSString *)folder name:(NSString *)namefolder

{   
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSArray* items = [self fetchFolderItemsWithFolderID:folder name:namefolder]; //   <- List Files/dirs in directory namefolder

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   // Create box object "item" to traverse folderItemsArray
    //BoxItem * item = (BoxItem *)[self.folderItemsArray objectEnumerator]; why do you need this line.
    for (BoxItem *item in items)
    {
        if([item.type isEqualToString:BoxAPIItemTypeFolder])
            {
                NSLog(@"SubFolder id %@", item.modelID);
                NSLog(@"SubFolder name %@", item.name);
                [self traverseItemsWithFolderID:item.modelID name:item.name];

            }
    }

    });
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually does not work: it stops at the first iteration (root folder)